# PHP code for login / logout not working correctly - PHP

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4

Having some issues with my login/logout php code appearing correctly in my nav bar. When the user is logged in, I wish for the navbar to show 'logout' and vice versa.

At the top of my header.php page:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  require "includes/dbh.inc.php";
?>
```

Snippet of the navbar code further down in header.php:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand text-left" href="index.php">iStudy University <i class="fas fa-graduation-cap"></i></a>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-dark navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myTogglerNav"
                aria-controls="myTogglerNav" aria-label="Toggle Navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>  <!-- Aria controls are for assistive screen readers -->

        <section class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myTogglerNav">
        <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link px-3" href="index.php"><i class="fas fa-home"><span class="nav-text">&nbsp; Home</span></i></a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link px-3" href="about.html"><i class="fas fa-info-circle"><span class="nav-text">&nbsp; About</span></i></a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link px-3" href="contact.html"><i class="fas fa-envelope"><span class="nav-text">&nbsp; Contact Us</span></i></a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link px-3" href="signup.php"><i class="fas fa-check-square"><span class="nav-text">&nbsp; Sign Up</span></i></a>
               <?php  
                    if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
                      echo "<a class='nav-item nav-link px-3' action='includes/login.inc.php' href='login.php'><i class='fas fa-sign-in-alt'><span class='nav-text'>&nbsp; Login</span></i></a>";
                    } else {
                      echo "<a class='nav-item nav-link px-3' action='includes/logout.inc.php' href='index.php'><i class='fas fa-sign-out-alt'><span class='nav-text'>&nbsp; Logout</span></i></a>";
                    }
                ?>
        </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</nav>
```

However, when I go to index.php, 'logout' is appearing as if the user has already logged in, please can someone give me some guidance as to where the mistake is. [image: What you see before logging in]

** Please note I'm not entirely sure if I can put an action within the code like I have....However I was following a YouTube tutorial and these were the pages that contained a lot of code which contained php and mySQLi in.**

```
action='includes/logout.inc.php
action='includes/login.inc.php
```

Comment: Does the session get started in the code where your nav bar is

Comment: Hi @RiggsFolly I'm not 100% sure where the session is suppose to be started so I placed in it my header.php page which is included on all pages on the site apart from index (as had to do a workaround on the index.php page), so there's no header included, therefore I just placed the code of <?php
  session_start();
?> at the top of the page....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use

```
$_SESSION['id']
```

to check for user login. Every session gets an id when started. Instead set a session variable like

$_SESSION['user_id']

or sth. when the user logs in and check against that variable.

Comment: Hello @Olafant, I've seen that in a page called login.inc.php there is the below code:
          $_SESSION['id'] = $row['idUsers'];
          $_SESSION['uid'] = $row['uidUsers'];
          $_SESSION['email'] = $row['emailUsers'];

Not sure if that affects which one I should choose, but I have used 'id' and 'idUsers' still no luck

Comment: You really need to learn the basics before playing with login stuff for websites. [http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) And you shouldn't use code that you don't understand. Especially for safety-related things like login and database.